# Read and send a mp4 file from in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, html5-video, http-response-codes

I am using the following code to read a mp4 file from the server and send it over http. My server side is a mvc4 controller. Funny thing is the video renders fine in Chrome. But not getting anything on ios devices so I am thinking this could be a response stream header problem. Anything I am missing?

> ```
>         var stream = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
>         var result = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK)
>         {
>             Content = new StreamContent(stream)
>         };
>         result.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("video/mp4");
>         result.Content.Headers.ContentRange = new ContentRangeHeaderValue(0, stream.Length);
>         result.Content.Headers.Add("filename", fileName);
>         return result;
> ```

This is the response header if it gives any clues:

```
Cache-Control:no-cache
Content-Length:2236480
Content-Range:bytes 0-2236480/*
Content-Type:video/mp4
Date:Fri, 24 May 2013 14:39:11 GMT
Expires:-1
filename:3.mp4
Pragma:no-cache
Server:Microsoft-IIS/7.5
X-AspNet-Version:4.0.30319
X-Powered-By:ASP.NET
```

Comment: When I set the source attribute to that file on the server like below it works. Only time it doesn't work is when I try to write it on the response with the above code.

Comment: <video width="320" height="240" controls="controls" preload="auto">
            <source src="/video/3_formatted.mp4" type="video/mp4">
           
        </video>

Answer (score 2):

I believe this is an encoder issue on iOS devices. iOS iPhone devices from what I know, use H.264 mp4 encoding. You should try Baseline level 3 encoding for the videos. You can find more info [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/StreamingMediaGuide/FrequentlyAskedQuestions/FrequentlyAskedQuestions.html).

Comment: Do you mean I need to change my source video file reformatting it with that encoding?

Comment: Tried with a video with H.264 coding and still the same thing. Works in Chrome. Does not work on a IOS device.