# How do I setup ContentType of Azure Blob correctly?

Tags: azure, mime-types, content-type, azure-blob-storage, azure-management-api

In my Web API I use the following code for creating the blob:

```
        var container = Client.GetContainerReference(DefaultContainer);
        var blockBlob = container.GetBlockBlobReference(blobName);

        blockBlob.UploadFromStream(fileStream);

        blockBlob.Properties.ContentType = "video/mp4";
        blockBlob.SetProperties();
```

I **need** the ContentType header value to be `video/mp4` when the file is downloaded from outside.

However, when I downloading that file with external link, Azure doesn't add corresponding ContentType. (It doesn't attach actually any).

So, how can I achieve that?

Comment: I test on my side, click Download in Azure blob, there is a link opened in browser. It showed a mp4 file. Then I right click save as, it download a mp4 file in my local folder. And I set a break point to see the properties of blob. it shows the correct content type like this:
https://image.ibb.co/kxnEuR/blobtype.png. So I'm not sure how you operate this.

Comment: The ContentType is a header which webserver returns with the file. In your case it's just a metadata which you pass to Azure via SDK.
http://ibb.co/d64oM6
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms525208%28v=vs.90%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Comment: So it seems that your issue is more related with web api, instead of Azure. The web api just support json or xml types by default. If we want to show 'video/mp4' type, we need to add the corresponding content type for it. You could add content type like this :response.Headers.Add("ContentType", "video/mp4"). Or you could read link:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16736439/read-and-send-a-mp4-file-from-in-c-sharp

Comment: The issue has nothing to do with Web Api at all. The file is being added the same way as you tried to add it. And further downloading of the file is done via direct link from outside of any other app.

Comment: The above code is right. But  I'm not sure how you do about the further operation.Could you provide more details? Your code or screenshot. I'm glad to help you.

Comment: @Agat, it seems that there is no issue in your mentioned code, I also do a demo on my side. I upload a demo  .mp4 to azure blob. You  could click the [link](https://wxtom.blob.core.windows.net/mycontainer/SampleVideo_1280x720_1mb.mp4) to download to check. You mentioned down from direct link, does it means that via blob url.

Comment: @Agat In your [mentioned image](http://ibb.co/d64oM6) is a .css file not .mp4 file, please have try to change the blob name with {blobname}.mp4

Comment: @TomSun, the image attached was for Janley, which couldn't fully catch what ContentType I am referring to. Of course, I need the the ContentType for .mp4 file. Regarding the code, I found some other sources which all mention the same, but the files I receive from my blobs still don't have the ContentType applied. So I am wandering, if that might be related to some caching or other Azure settings?

Comment: May be related to caching, you could use incognito window to test it again. Also you could use the [Azure storage exploer](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/features/storage-explorer/) to the check blob property.

Comment: @TomSun, yes, I did that all. The ContentType I check with specially created ConsoleApp, as browser doesn't allow to see the ContentType in that case: Chrome just starts to download the file (which actually means that it's not treat as video, otherwise it would just play it). The Azure Storage Explorer also rather ok, unless I miss something with that. It's not quite intuitive at the moment (lots of properties and almost no documentation where should I use them in practice).

Comment: @Agat I think you need to use `blockBlob.FetchAttributes();` before setting the content type

Comment: @Agat, if you could see the blob property ContentType is `video/mp4`. I am sure there is no related to Azure setting. You could copy the blob url to the browser directly and check it again.  You also could it try with other browsers.

Answer (score 4):

You need to get the properties/metadata first before updating them, so your code should be:

```
var container = Client.GetContainerReference(DefaultContainer);
var blockBlob = container.GetBlockBlobReference(blobName);
blockBlob.UploadFromStream(fileStream);

// Set the content type
blockBlob.FetchAttributes();
blockBlob.Properties.ContentType = "text/html";
blockBlob.SetProperties();
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, @thomas, but I am just totally frustrated! Nothing changes for me at all whatever I do! Still the same result. Might I just miss something? Like subscription level required or something else? I can't see any impact my code does on the blobs. Could you clarify the following: this all is related to Storage Accounts/Containers/Particular Blog Container/Container Item (if navigate through Azure portal)? Also, right after applying `SetProperties()`, where should I see those changes visually via the portal (Edit Metadata? Those are just empty)?

Comment: Have you tried the async method ? `FetchAttributesAsync, UploadFromStreamAsync, SetPropertiesAsync` ? Are you using a sas token to update the content type or the access key ?

Comment: Thomas, I am using AccountKey (storing whole ConnectionString in web.config). And also, `Async` methods don't like like change anything.

Comment: Could you give me a hint, where should I see the changes applied (or apply it manually) through Azure Portal?

Comment: this should be applied on the fly. did you have any error btw ?what do you mean by Async methods don't like like change anything

Comment: That means, that having the methods as Async doesn't change the whole picture. It's the same result for me. (I.e., no result. huh)
And also, I wish I had at least any error!

Comment: so the blockBlob.FetchAttributes(); does not work ? sorry dont really know how I can help

Comment: Ok, but could you give me a hint: in case if that does change the Properties, should I see it in some properties of that file through Azure Portal UI?

Comment: You can use the blob REST API to check the content type: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/get-blob-properties. you can check that the `Content-Type has been set correctly`. Is it possible that you disable video playing from chrome settings ?

Comment: It has nothing to do with Chrome (or any other browser). I see the ContentType is still default one when trying to access the file from Android app, as well as when checking it with HttpClient in my c# code.

Comment: Ok sorry dont really know. Tried on my side and it is ok.

Answer (score 0):

Azure blob falls to the default value of 'application/octet-stream' if nothing is provided. To get the correct mimetypes, this is what I did with my flask app:

```
@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def upload_file():

    if request.method == 'POST':
        f = request.files['file']
        mime_type = f.content_type
        print (mime_type)
        print (type(f))
        try:
            #blob_service.create_blob_from_path(container, f, f.filename)
            blob_service.create_blob_from_stream(container, f.filename, f,
            content_settings=ContentSettings(content_type=mime_type))
```

mime_type was passed to ContentSettings to get the current mimetypes of files uploaded to azure blob.